# AWS SNS ConfirmationSubscription PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Can someone provide a tutorial or guide on how to do ConfirmationSubscription of AWS SNS using PHP? I've already search in the internet but found out results dated 2010 to 2015 and it doesn't work properly.

Should I work using AWS PHP SDK v3?

If yes, will I have to set my AWS credential using SNS Client?

Please needed guidance. TY

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator

- Follow the SNS ConfirmationSubscription section.
- Make sure you be able to get the post data then get the SubscribeUrl.
- Once you have the SubscribeUrl, use http-client(https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient) to perform get and send operation.

$response = $httpClient->get(stripslashes($postMessageArr['SubscribeURL']))->send();